# Late static binding in php 5.3

Tags: php, php-5.3

Please go through below given code it is from php manual

```
<?php
class A {
    private function foo() {
        echo "success!\n";
    }
    public function test() {
        $this->foo();
        static::foo();
    }
}

class B extends A {
   /* foo() will be copied to B, hence its scope will still be A and
    * the call be successful */
}

class C extends A {
    private function foo() {
        /* original method is replaced; the scope of the new one is C */
    }
}

$b = new B();
$b->test();
$c = new C();
$c->test();   //fails
?>
```

can any one explain what is exactly going on here?

How come foo() will be copied to B ?

Comment: `foo()` will not be copied, it's inherited by its parent `A`. I don't understand your concrete problem. Of course it fails, because you made your method `foo` in `C` private. Make it public and it will work.

Comment: how come foo will be inherited? ...since it is private method...this is example from php manual

Comment: Yeah, it's just not accessible.

Comment: The [entire page you copied the example from in the Manual explains Late Static Binding](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php). Can you please clarify what you are not understanding or how the page is unclear to you?

Comment: in above example ...in class B...it is written that "foo() will be copied to B"...that is what confuse me...

Comment: @PoonamBhatt see the chapter on http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

Comment: tl;dr. If you declare C::foo as protected, problem goes away

Answer (score 4):

I remember now why late static binding is useful. Unfortunately, the php.net example is kind of poorly explained. See this (modified) example:

```
<?php
class A {
    private function foo() {
        echo __CLASS__;
    }
    public function test() {
        $this->foo();
        static::foo();
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public function foo()
    {
        echo __CLASS__;
    }
}

$b = new B();
$b->test();
?>
```

If you run the above code, you will notice that it works and you will get `AB`. Why?

- It works because `test()` is a public getter for `foo()`, so it does not matter if you call `test()` from an object of type `A`, or from an object of type `B`, that inherits from `A`, because `test()` will always have access to the private members of the class in which it is defined.
- In the first case `$this->foo();` will always call `A::foo()` because the binding is done locally, inside `A`'s scope, which is quite undesirable sometimes. See this comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php#83502
- In the second case, `static::foo();` instructs the interpreter to determine `$b`'s type and see in which class to try and find `foo()`. In this case, `B::foo()` is seen as an override method for `A::foo()`, so, basically, if `B::foo()` exists, it will be called, otherwise, the interpreter will look for `A::foo()`.
- Try to mark `B::foo()` as private and run the example I provided, to see what happens. I think this test and my rants above will clarify the issue for you ;)

Also, I accept any comments to my above points, because I haven't used PHP in quite a while.

Comment: Spoiler for my question: It might be a bit odd at first that it will try to access B::foo() from `A`'s perspective (don't forget that `test()` is defined in `A`), but, otherwise, it breaks encapsulation, so that's why `B::foo()` needs to be public, in order to work as an override method for `A::foo()`.

Comment: The second point in your list is only true for this example, not in general. If A::foo() is declared public or protected, the output would be "BB". This is because private functions cannot be overwritten.

Comment: Well, yes. I hope my example wasn't suggesting such a fallacy :) By the way, thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 2):

`foo` isn't copied to B per se (it is inherited but invisible; see Gordon's comment below). B inherits `A->foo`, which calls `A->test`. To demonstrate, look at what happens when you `echo __CLASS__` from within `test` and `foo` (and remove the `static::foo()` call, which is causing the error):

```
class A {
    private function foo() {
        echo __CLASS__."->foo\n";
        echo "success!\n";
    }
    public function test() {
        echo __CLASS__."->test\n";
        $this->foo();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
A->test
A->foo
success!
A->test
A->foo
success!
```

This is one of the fundamentals of inheritance as it relates to [information hiding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_hiding)/[encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29). This allows you to do things like this:

```
class ListOfThings {
    // internal structure (top secret!)
    private $_list = array();

    // add item to list
    public function add($item) {
        $this->_list[] = $item;
    }

    // return number of items in list
    public function count() {
        return count($this->_list);
    }
}

class ListOfStates extends ListOfThings {

    // do we have all 50 states?
    public function allStatesListed() {
        return $this->count() === 50;
    }

    // try to access internal structure of ListOfThings
    public function accessInternalStructure() {
        sort($this->_list);
    }
}

$states = new ListOfStates;
$states->add('ME');
$states->add('NH');
$states->add('VT');
$states->add('RI');
$states->add('CT');
var_dump($states->count());
var_dump($states->allStatesListed());
$states->accessInternalStructure();
```

Output:

```
int(5)
bool(false)

Warning: sort() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given...
```

As you can see, `ListOfStates` is able to use all the public functionality of `ListOfThings`, even though those functions all depend on the private variable `$_list`. That said, `ListOfStates` cannot directly manipulate `$_list`; it can only act on `$_list` indirectly through the public functions defined in `ListOfThings`.

Check out the [Visibility](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php) page in the PHP documentation for more details on such things.

Comment: foo is private method...and as per visibility private method are not inherited to child class

Comment: @Poonam it *is* inherited. But it is not visible, which is why you cannot access it. See http://codepad.viper-7.com/B7OWyr

Comment: @Gordon That's not really a good example, because you're using a variable, not a function. Variables contain data that for sure needs to be bound to the instance, so there is a difference.